# Align span in Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, sass

So I'm trying to align the Swipe Icon to the right without `padding-right: 0;` doesn't work:(

Herse some Code and Images:
[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <span class="c-visualslider__swipeicon"></span>
</div>
```

and my SCSS:

```
.c-visualslider {
    padding: 528px 0 80px;
    position: relative;
    background: map-get($colors, black);

    &__swipeicon {
        height: 34px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        width: 32px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: (image);
```

Answer (score 3):

**add three css properties to swipeicon**

```
display: flex; 
justify-content: flex-end; 
margin: 8px 0 0 auto;
```

**try this**

```
.c-visualslider {
    padding: 528px 0 80px;
    position: relative;
    background: map-get($colors, black);

    &__swipeicon {
        height: 34px;
        width: 32px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: (image);

        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin: 8px 0 0 auto;
```